# X Robots Tag noindex specific page

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, noindex

I have a Privacy Policy page on my website www.domain/privacy-policy/ which I would like to noindex with the X Robots Tag. I have tried the following code but it does not match

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^privacy-policy - [env=NOINDEXFOLLOW:true]
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=NOINDEXFOLLOW

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Question has been edited to include full htaccess file for clarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `www.domain/privacy-policy/`

"privacy-policy" is in the URL-path, not the query string, as you have used in your directive. Try something like the following instead, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy - [env=NOINDEXFOLLOW:true]

Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

However, it would be preferable to use mod_setenvif instead of mod_rewrite to set the environment variable:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/privacy-policy" NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

**UPDATE:** Since you are using a *front-controller* (WordPress directives), the `RewriteRule` directive to set the environment variable would need to go at the top of your `.htaccess` file, before the WP directives. By positioning this directive after the WP directives it simply does not get processed. (The `SetEnvIf` and `Header` directives can appear later in the file if you wish.)

However, since you are using a *front-controller* and rewriting all requests to `index.php`, the `NOINDEXFOLLOW` variable is not being set in the request you are seeing. After the rewrite to `index.php` Apache changes this to `REDIRECT_NOINDEXFOLLOW` (`REDIRECT_` prefix) and this is what you need to check for in the `Header` directive. So, in summary:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/privacy-policy" NOINDEXFOLLOW
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=REDIRECT_NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

(Not quite so intuitive.)

And if you use the `RewriteRule` directive instead to set the `NOINDEXFOLLOW` environment variable then this must appear at the start of the file.

Comment: It's still not matching

Comment: Have you tried both the methods above? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Neither method works. I have edited the question with full htaccess

Comment: Ah, you have a couple of problems with using WordPress/front-controller. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @ReinaldoGil The update with the `REDIRECT_` prefix should work on any _Apache_ server where the URL is internally rewritten in `.htaccess`. So, any CMS/framework that uses a front-controller pattern, like WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, Laravel etc. etc.

Comment: @MrWhite yes, thank you! It was very hard to find this.