# htaccess header for specific domain?

Tags: .htaccess

I have three environments:

```
env.com
env-uat.com
env-pre.com
```

All three pages run the same code. I want env-uat.com and env-pre.com to both get this in the htaccess:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

This will effectively completely unindex these pages, including PDF files etc. But I don't want to affect env.com.

How can I make the Header X-Robots-Tag only be added for env-uat.com and env-pre.com and NOT env.com?

** UPDATE **

From what I could find so far, it would seem you can only do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828216/x-robots-tag-noindex-specific-page):

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/privacy-policy" NOINDEXFOLLOW
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=REDIRECT_NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

But this makes it specific to a PAGE. I want it specific to a DOMAIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Starkeen was right up to here :

```
SetEnvIf host ^(env-uat\.com|host2\.com)$ NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

So , you could include the domains that you want to be involved in this Env like this :

```
SetEnvIf host ^(env-uat|env-pre)\.com NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

Then you should attach the Env with same name like this :

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

Not like this :

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=REDIRECT_NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

The line above will look to Env its name is  REDIRECT_NOINDEXFOLLOW not NOINDEXFOLLOW and it is diffrent case from this question [X Robots Tag noindex specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828216/x-robots-tag-noindex-specific-page)
 That was about matching against Request_URI and for special case .

So , the code should look like this :

```
SetEnvIf host ^(env-uat|env-pre)\.com NOINDEXFOLLOW
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

Answer (score 2):

You can match against `Host` header using `SetEnvIf` directive.

To make the `Header X-Robots-Tag` only  available  for a specific host ( env-uat.com ) you could use something like the following :

```
SetEnvIf host ^env-uat\.com$ NOINDEXFOLLOW
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=REDIRECT_NOINDEXFOLLOW
```

To make this available for multiple hosts ,you could use the following :

```
SetEnvIf host ^(env-uat\.com|host2\.com)$ NOINDEXFOLLOW
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=REDIRECT_NOINDEXFOLLOW
```